# Getting error in saving data in Internal Storage in android

Tags: android

I am making an app that takes two strings through edittext. I want to store these strings in Internal Storage but I am getting error: "java.io.FILENOTFOUNDEXCEPTION".

```
            public class MyActivity extends Activity {

public Button save;
public EditText user;
public EditText pass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String un = (String) user.getText().toString();
            String pw = (String) pass.getText().toString();
            //Creating file for saving username and passwords
            String PRONTO = "PrivateData";
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(PRONTO, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(un.getBytes());
            fos.close();

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Post your error to let others begin

Comment: change the filename for something like file for example "cred.dat"

Comment: Done that but still getting that error

Comment: Are you testing on a real device or emulator?

Comment: I am not testing it I am getting that error in java file

Comment: You can't get an exception "in java file", that doesn't make any sense. Please show the full code around the snippet you provided.

Comment: Its saying as unhandled exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(PRONTO, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

with

```
FileOutputStream fos;
try {
    fos = openFileOutput(PRONTO, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(un.getBytes());
    fos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: It removed the error from that but error in following line is still there  
fos.write(un.getBytes());
            fos.close();

Comment: Anyway surrounding all three lines in try and catch removed that eroor

Comment: Sure there is, check my answer again.